# Traits with parameterized associated types

Tags: rust, traits

I come from a C++ background and was wondering if I could [code up a trait for use in the `foo` and `bar` functions](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=853059946a20e9b1cde7942efa4c7712&version=nightly):

```
#![feature(alloc)]

use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

pub trait MyTrait {
    /// Value type
    type VAL;
    /// Strongly boxed type
    /// Will be constrained to something like Box, Rc, Arc
    type SB;
    /// Weakly boxed type
    type WB;
}

struct MyFoo;

impl MyTrait for MyFoo {
    type VAL = i64;
    type SB = Rc<i64>;
    type WB = Weak<i64>;
}

fn foo<T: MyTrait>(value: T::VAL) {}
// Uncomment
// fn bar<T: MyTrait>(rc_val: T::SB<T::VAL>) {}

fn main() {
    let x = 100 as i64;
    let y = Rc::new(200 as i64);
    foo::<MyFoo>(x);
    // Uncomment
    // bar::<MyFoo>(y);

    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

`foo` works, but the nested type argument `rc_val` in `bar` causes problems:

```
error[E0109]: type parameters are not allowed on this type
  --> src/main.rs:25:34
   |
25 | fn bar<T: MyTrait>(rc_val: T::SB<T::VAL>) {}
   |                                  ^^^^^^ type parameter not allowed
```

I saw something about [this](https://botbot.me/mozilla/rust/msg/26182512/) on the IRC channel related to *Higher Kinded Types*, but I'm not that familiar with functional programming. Can someone suggest a workaround for what I'm trying to do here? This code was tested in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=853059946a20e9b1cde7942efa4c7712&version=nightly) with the `nightly` build.

Comment: Convention would change `VAL`, `SB` and `WB` to things like `Value`, `Strong` and `Weak`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The design means that [you should be able to just write](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d58447a6dc8d3c9f5a538696b9619317&version=nightly)

```
fn bar<T: MyTrait>(rc_val: T::SB) {}
```

The trait implementation of `MyTrait` for `MyFoo` already specifies the type parameter for `SB`.

If you want to connect `SB` and `VAL`, one can place trait bounds on `SB`, e.g.:

```
trait MyTrait {
    type VAL;
    type SB: Deref<Target = Self::VAL>;
}
```